# Always discard result for a parser combinator

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

In earlier versions of scala the discard method existed to throw away the results of a parser:

```
lazy val throwThisAway: Parser[String] = (ows ~> discard(comma | EOF | EOL)) <~ ows
```

How may that be achieved in current versions of the library .. i.e while simply doing

```
otherParser ~ throwThisAway ~ anotherParser ^^ { case a ~ b // only 2, not 3, parser results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply reference the extra parser result but not use it:

```
otherParser ~ throwThisAway ~ anotherParser ^^ { case a ~ x ~ b => // eg.: SomeCaseClass(a,b)
```

or even:

```
otherParser ~ throwThisAway ~ anotherParser ^^ { case a ~ _ ~ b => ...
```

Comment: Well i'm going to guess that's about all we get. The older approach is sometimes more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<~` (sequential composition that keeps only the left) or `~>` (sequential composition that keeps only the right) instead. For example:

```
(otherParser <~ throwThisAway) ~ anotherParser ^^ { case a ~ b => ... }
```

Or

```
otherParser ~ (throwThisAway ~> anotherParser) ^^ { case a ~ b => ... }
```

Comment: Thanks.. but that's what is all over the place *already* in my parsers. Notice that you have to put the parens around it. The purpose of the question was to obtain a means to avoid that being necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that... You can avoid the parenthesis if you define a parser such as `otherParser <~ throwThisAway` and then use it in the final parser. But that is unfortunately less clear...